# How do I make std::sort not have name collision between std::swap and my namespace's templated swap?

Tags: c++, namespaces, overload-resolution, ambiguous-call

I want to use `std::sort`, but the compile is failing with error `C2668: std::swap: ambiguous call to overloaded function` because there is a templated `swap()` function defined in my namespace that would be hard to get rid of. I don't care which `swap` it uses, but how do I make either one of them go away when compiling `sort()`?

I understand that it's ambiguous because `my::swap` is in the same namespace as `my::Obj`, and I don't care which version of `swap` gets used. I just have to overcome the namespace collision. This is part of a very large code base that I don't own so I'm hoping for a solution that is local to my code and presumably allows `my::Obj` and `my::swap`to both stay in namespace `my`.

```
namespace my
{
    template<class T> void swap(T a, T b)
    {
    }

    struct Obj
    {
    };

    void doSortStuff()
    {
        std::vector<Obj> arr;
        std::sort(arr.begin(), arr.end());
    }
};
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is this call to swap() ambiguous?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34075718/why-is-this-call-to-swap-ambiguous)

Comment: Why not put your templated swap in its own namespace and then call it using that namespace?

Comment: are you `using namespace std`?

Comment: @BilalSaleem Probably because the call is inside `std::sort`.

Comment: See this example answer to a similar post:   https://stackoverflow.com/a/51165683/2785528  Which explains 2 options.  You can move your code, as simply as possible, into a 'distinguishing' namespace.  Or, you can move your code into a 'distinguishing' class.  Either will end the ambiguity.  Of course, without more info on your code ... well, you really should provide a [MCVE]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A workaround is to create a better overload:

```
// No modifiable code
namespace my
{
    template<class T> void swap(T a, T b) { /*.. */ }
    struct Obj { /*..*/ };
}

// Your code:
namespace my
{
    void swap(Obj& lhs, Obj& rhs)
    {
        // my::swap<Obj&>(lhs, rhs);
        std::swap(lhs, rhs);
    }
}

// In namespace you want.
void doSortStuff()
{
    std::vector<my::Obj> arr;
    std::sort(arr.begin(), arr.end());
}
```

Then, between the 3 valid overloads, all are exact match, but the **non**-template is preferred.

Answer (score 2):

Contrary to some comments and surprising to some this error happens without `using namespace std`. Here is a minimal example to understand what is going on:

```
namespace like_std
{
    template<class T> void swap(T a, T b) {}

    template <class T> auto test(T x, T y)
    {
        swap(x, y); // (1) ambiguous call
    }
}

namespace my
{
    template<class T> void swap(T a, T b) {}

    struct Obj {};

    void doStuff()
    {
        like_std::test(Obj{}, Obj{});
    }
};
```

You do a call to a function from `like_std` and inside this function there is an unqualified call to `swap`. For this call:

- `like_std::swap` is a candidate because is in the same namespace as the call to `swap`
- `my::swap` is a candidate because of ADL: it's brought in because it's in the same namespace as one of the arguments to the call of `swap`

Since neither of those is better there is an ambiguity.

The reason why the call to `swap` is unqualified is so that it will pick up a custom `swap` if it's defined, **but** that works only if the custom `swap` is a better candidate, which is assumed for a custom `swap` function.

The solution, as [Jarod42](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52999721/2805305) showed is to define a better candidate `swap` function.

Comment: Thanks for this very good explanation. It does clarify why @jarod42's solution works.

Answer (score -1):

You are probably `using namespace std;`.

In this case, the compiler does not know what to choose as it makes all `std::` members available without typing it automatically, where both functions are suitable:

```
using namespace std;
swap(a, b); //your swap
swap(a, b); //std::swap
```

As in this case, you have strict function calls:

```
std::swap(a, b); //from std
swap(a, b); // your one
```

This is actually a very good example of why you should avoid `using namespace std`. Good luck!

Update:  This can be your solution - move your `swap()` outside of `std::sort()` usage:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

namespace detail
{
  struct someContainer
  {
    someContainer(int &v)
    {
      value = v;
    }
    int value;
    someContainer &operator = (const someContainer & rhs)
    {
      this->value = rhs.value;
    }
    bool operator == (someContainer &rhs) const
    {
      return this->value == rhs.value;
    }
    bool operator <= (someContainer &rhs) const
    {
      return this->value <= rhs.value;
    }
    bool operator >= (someContainer &rhs) const
    {
      return this->value >= rhs.value;
    }
    bool operator > (someContainer &rhs) cosnt
    {
      return this->value > rhs.value;
    }
    bool operator < (someContainer &rhs) const
    {
      return this->value < rhs.value;
    }
  };
  void doSomeStuff()
  {
    std::vector<someContainer> vec;
    for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i)
    {
      vec.push_back(someContainer(i));
    }
    std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());
  }
}

namespace mySwap
{
  template< class T >
  void swap(T &a, T &b)
  {
     T c = a;
     a = b;
     b = c;
  }
}
int main()
{
  detail::doSomeStuff();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm not using namespace std, though. But the code calling std::sort is in the same namespace as the other version of swap. I can see why they're both pulled in, but what's the most elegant way to express which one I want?

Comment: @AlltheRage I think that the easiest way is not to use your custom swap as standard one already exists. Why would you ever need that? But you also can move you swap to another namespace where std::sort() is not called.

Comment: Thanks. This is part of a big code base that I don't own. I only control a small piece. They wrote the whole thing without using STL, which is why they have their own swap. If I can't modify their swap, do you have any other ideas?

Comment: @AlltheRage then, I think, the only idea is to implement your own sort() which is quicksort algorithm in C++

Comment: the error appears even without `using namespace std` because of ADL

Comment: @bolov I told about possible `using namespace std` problem before he exampled the code, so I updated it then